# Controlling visibility of 2 divs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm trying to use a tabbed interface to display content on a website. The first set of divs is the content (text) and the second is an associated image in a div outside the div containing the text as follows:

```
<div id="side-img-container">
 <div class="side-img" id="image_1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="side-img" id="image_2"><img src="image2.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="side-img" id="image_3"><img src="image3.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="side-img" id="image_4"><img src="image4.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="side-img" id="image_5"><img src="image5.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div id="content>
<ul class="tabs">
 <li><a href="#tab_1">Tab 1</a></div>
 <li><a href="#tab_2">Tab 2</a></div>
 <li><a href="#tab_3">Tab 3</a></div>
 <li><a href="#tab_4">Tab 4</a></div>
 <li><a href="#tab_5">Tab 5</a></div>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
 <div class="tab_content" id="tab_1">Content 1</div>
 <div class="tab_content" id="tab_2">Content 2</div>
 <div class="tab_content" id="tab_3">Content 3</div>
 <div class="tab_content" id="tab_4">Content 4</div>
 <div class="tab_content" id="tab_5">Content 5</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This uses the following Jquery to make the tabs work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//When page loads...
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute     value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```

Is there any way the above javascript can be added to/adapted so that the corresponding image tab is displayed when a content tab is displayed ie: tab_1 and image_1 etc. ?

Comment: Hmz... doable are the li mapped 1-1 with the images ?

Comment: There is one list item for each image and each content div. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your HTML is invalid - you're closing `<li>` list items with `</div>` tags. You've also forgotten to close the quote surrounding the `#content` element's `id` attribute value.

The original JavaScript code isn't particularly efficient, so we might as well rewrite it. Using this code, you do not need each of the tab content to have a `class` attribute, which certainly lightens up the HTML quite a bit:

```
// Select all of the tab contents, then hide them
// Cache elements that need to be reused
var tabContents = $(".tab_container, #side-img-container").children().hide(),
    tabs = $("ul.tabs li");

// Show the first tab's content, and add in the active class
tabs.first().addClass("active");
tabContents.filter(':first-child').show();

// Attach click event handler
tabs.click(function() {
    // Cache the clicked on tab element
    var $this = $(this),
        // Obtain the element index number
        activeTab = $this.index() + 1;

    // Only change tabs if the clicked tab isn't active
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        // Remove the 'active' class from the original anchor and add it to the current one
        $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        // Hide all of the other tabs and fade in the active one
        tabContents.siblings().hide().filter(':nth-child(' + activeTab + ')').fadeIn();
    }

    return false;
});
```

See a simple demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/ND7nU/

Comment: my bad, I hand typed the code instead of copy-pasta, its valid in the actual page tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('div.side-img').hide();
$('div.side-img:first').show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $('div.side-img').eq($(this).index()).show();
    // remaining code 
}
```

Comment: This looks like something I tried before I came here, Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place n the code. Can you clarify where this should be going in the above javascript?

Comment: the above 2 lines of code, just put before click function.And `$('div.side-img').eq($(this).index()).show();` inside click function wherever you want to put it.

Comment: @mandrill, I think it would replace your code - see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/BN5Tj/) - if you still need the active class you would add/remove it along with the show/hide bits

Answer (score 0):

Bit quick and dirty from the top of my head:

```
var s = activeTab.attr('id');
var num = s.substr(4, 1);
var imgstr = "#image-" + num;

$(".side-img").hide();
$(imgstr).show();
```

Edit: You can use this anywhere in the tab click event handler.
Edit 2: var s = etc Fix.

Comment: There's no such thing as `Id()` - you're looking for `activeTab.id`, assuming `activeTab` is a DOM element, or `activeTab.attr('id')` if `activeTab` is a jQuery object. Given that in the original code, `activeTab` is a selector string, this is completely unnecessary - just do `activeTab.substr(4, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/xcQmx/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick except its not displaying anything (either the content or the image) when the page first loads

Comment: Yes. I hid everything to make it easier to see what's going on. Updating with IMG1/CONTENT1 not hidden.